# Populating ComboBoxes VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this VBA code:

```
Sub sendByCustomForm()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sText As String

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body

    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\myCustomForm.oft")
    MsgBox sText, vbInformation, "alert"

    With msg
        'Set body format to HTML
        .BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" + sText + "</BODY></HTML>"
        .Display
    End With
Next olItem    
End Sub
```

That template has 2 ComboBoxes that I want to populate, but how can I do this?

When I try this:

```
msg.ComboBox1.AddItem "item"
```

it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'For Access
msg.ComboBox1.RowSource = msg.ComboBox1.Rowsource & ";'item'"
```

Update:

```
With ComboBox        
.AddItem "Option 1"        
.AddItem "Option 2"        
.AddItem "Option 3"
End With
```

Comment: same error: "object doesn't support this property or method" =/

Comment: This got me curious, so I started some reading.  It says to use a with/end for combobox and additem.  I was doing it with Access thinking it might work the same.  Maybe try the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub emailfromexcel()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = "person@email.com"
    .BCC = thebcc
    .Subject = "This subject"
    .Body = "This body"
    .Display
    .Send
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```