# How to add items to a combobox in a form in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am new to VBA. I want to create a form where a user selects an item of a combobox and the selection runs a macro.I created a user form in VBA but I am unable to add items to the Combobox.When a user opens the form I want the choices in the combobox to be already loaded.how can I accomplish this?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this;

[Excel VBA ComboBox Lists](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html)

from here;

[vba- Can a combobox present more then one column on it's textbox part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867461/vba-can-a-combobox-present-more-then-one-column-on-its-textbox-part)

and this may help;

[Populating ComboBoxes VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234742/populating-comboboxes-vba)

I added a sort of demo here;

[Playing with populating boxes.xlsm](https://github.com/MakeCents/Excel_VBA)

Answer (score 22):

The method I prefer assigns an array of data to the combobox. Click on the body of your userform and change the "Click" event to "Initialize". Now the combobox will fill upon the initializing of the userform. I hope this helps.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ComboBox1.List = Array("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008", "1009", "1010")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a combobox dynamically in VBA? I need to create one at run-time inside sheet1 whenever the workbook opens. Appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another answer:

```
With DinnerComboBox
.AddItem "Italian"
.AddItem "Chinese"
.AddItem "Frites and Meat"
End With
```

Source: [Show the](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)