# Assigning values to Combo box in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, listbox

I am trying to set the values of the combo box to 0, 1, and 2 (hard coded  values and not a cell reference) but it does not seem to work.  I have tried setting the `RowSourceType" to 1 and to`Value List`, but I am getting compile errors every time.  For example, the following code does not work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.errorComboBox.RowSourceType = "Value List"
Me.errorComboBox.RowSource = "0;1;2"
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.errorComboBox.RowSourceType = 1
Me.errorComboBox.RowSource = "0;1;2"
End Sub
```

I am getting errors on the `RowSourceType` line for both.  How can I do this?

Comment: djikay's answers appears to be correct.  Also, it appears that the syntax you were using would be correct in Access.  I'm sure there is a reason for the difference, but it is a bit irritating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To statically populate the list of a combo box in Excel, try something like this:

```
Me.errorComboBox.List = Array("0", "1", "2")
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946317/how-to-add-items-to-a-combobox-in-a-form-in-excel-vba) contains links and other examples to achieve what you want.

Comment: To add to this, it should be done on the userform Initialize event.  works perfect though.  You can also add single values using the .addItem method.. Just found this out.  Thanks.

Comment: `RowSource` actually is usable in Excel. The syntax is a string address, e.g., `Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "A1:A10"`, which will use that range in the ActiveSheet. RowSource is generally not the way to go, but it's the only way to include column headers. RowSourceType does seem to be unusable, so I"m not sure why it's there.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Good to know, thanks. Edited my answer so others don't get confused.

Comment: You bet. Changed my "-" to a "+". List is the way to go.