# Error 381, Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to assign values to a Combobox, but am getting run-time error 381. Does anyone know why? Here is the code where the error occurs -

```
LastAddress = Sheets("TempList").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Address
ComboBox1.List = "TempList!A2:" & LastAddress
```

Thanks so much!

Here is the revised code that worked. Thanks much.

```
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim wss As Worksheet

Set wss = Sheets("TempList")

With wss
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    myArray = Sheets("TempList").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    Sheets("CompRecTool").Activate
    ComboBox1.List = myArray
End With
```

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946317/how-to-add-items-to-a-combobox-in-a-form-in-excel-vba) help any?

Comment: Does a comboBox have to include an array? I'm not sure why I can't add a range of cells from a sheet?

Comment: you can click on the DATA tab, go into Data Validation, and set it to a "list" with a reference, ie if the list is located on a worksheet called "List" in cells A1:A10, the reference would be =List!$A$1:$A$10

Comment: Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Sheets("TempList").Range("A2:A10")

Sheets("CompRecTool").Activate
ComboBox1.List = myArray

Comment: The code above worked. I just need to figure out how to declare myArray based on an undefined LastRow

Comment: is `LastAddress` a String Type? Also maybe use the `(0,0)` arguments for the `Address` to remove the absolute referencing `$`?

Comment: It would help if you included more of your macro, not just the two lines that cause the issue.  As you can see, without seeing more, we can just offer some ideas..which may work in the two lines above, but not when you run your whole macro.

Comment: I posed the revised code that ended up working for me. Thanks everyone.