# Combo box - dynamic search

Tags: vba

Dears, 
Is it possible to write a code that could be attached to a combo box and it would dynamically search the item from the list?

I mean, I would like to have something like data validation - but it would search dynamically through the list and suggest the response (dynamically)?

I found a tutorial with ISNUMBERS and INDEX, MATCH formulas, but it is quite complicated to be applied...

Comment: You can just add the valid items to the combobox, and then as the user types into it, it will attempt to match what they are typing to the list. It's automatic... or is that not what you mean?

Comment: how would i add this? Is this in combo box properties?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946317/how-to-add-items-to-a-combobox-in-a-form-in-excel-vba

Comment: It shows how to create this in a user form... i am struggling how to resolve this...

Comment: You arent trying to create it in a user form?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to do this not in a user form ?