# what is wrong with this line of vba code for Excel Print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox with list of page size in excel. i want to change page sizes with combobox selection change.

Following is not working

```
Public Sub UpdateSize()
Dim Papersizetext As String 

Papersizetext = "xlPaper" & Worksheets("Static").Range("B7").value 'A4 is the value in cell B7

shgenerate.PageSetup.PaperSize = Papersizetext 'not working 
shgenerate.PageSetup.PaperSize = "xlPaper" & Combobox1.value 'this also not working

shgenerate.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4 'is working - i want above to work. 

'shgenerate is sheet name

End sub
```

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpapersize` - `xlPaperA4` is equivalent to 9. It's an enum member, not a string. You could write yourself a helper function to actually return `xlPaperA4` given the concatenated `xlPaper` and input `A4` - `Select Case` would be useful.

Comment: But how can i make it work. as i have list with page size name.

Comment: @ BigBen Can you please provide code. i am new to vba

Comment: What values do you have in combobox1?

Comment: I got list of available sizes in combobox with help of code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188638/how-get-list-of-available-page-size-in-combobox-and-change-size   helped by @HTH

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz Its Size names A4, A3 and so on

Comment: You could also use a multi-column combo and have those enum values in a hidden column. Then use those values in that hidden column as the input for your paper size setting.

Answer (score 1):

You could whip up your own function to parse the input and return the correct enum member:

```
Private Function PaperSize(ByVal rawSize As String) As Long
    Select Case rawSize
        Case "A4"
            PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        Case "A3"
            PaperSize = xlPaperA3
        Case "A5"
            PaperSize = xlPaperA5
        Case Else
            PaperSize = xlPaperUser ' or some other default 
    End Select
End Function
```

For more complex paper sizes, such as `"Letter 8.5"x11" 22x28cm"` or `"Legal 8.5"x14" 22x36cm"`, you could possibly use `InStr` to test of the existence of "Letter" and "Legal" to return `xlPaperLetter` and `xlPaperLegal`.

Regex might be another approach to parse out the dimensions.

Without more detail though, it's hard to give a satisfactory answer, as this question is actually quite a broad topic.

Comment: Thanks for your code But page sizes are dynamic. so can't be predefined.as above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188638/how-get-list-of-available-page-size-in-combobox-and-change-size that is why i want to change it with combox selection change. as combobox is updated with new sizes once printer adds new size.

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection - that's why you need a function to *parse* the combobox input.

Comment: you might be correct. but what if after i install printer drivers and a new size with name "ABC"  with width 8 inch and height 15 inch is created. how would i define the same in advance.

Comment: `xlPaperUser` maybe?

Comment: i ll take care of it.

Comment: Can you please provide code if its possible to change size with combobox selection change.

Comment: i am not getting details about xlPaperUser here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpapersize

Comment: Scroll all the way to the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211585/discussion-between-heavyload-collection-and-bigben).